# USB Connection problem for Android Lollipop

Tags: android, usb, android-hardware

Currently I'm developing an app that requires two hardware to connect to the device via USB. I'm encountering an error where the app can see the two devices but the app can only establish a connection to the last hardware inserted to the USB hub.

The android OS version is 5.1 and I used the UsbManager class.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

It happens at mReader.open()

Here is the code snippet where the error happens:

```
public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"BroadcastReceiver  onReceive");
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                            .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if(mReader.isSupported(device)){
                        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                                UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                            if (device != null) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"BroadcastReceiver  Opentask");
                                mReader.open(device);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                Log.d(TAG,"BroadcastReceiver  ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED");
                synchronized (this) {

                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                            .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (device != null && device.equals(mReader.getDevice())) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"BroadcastReceiver  Closetaks");
                        mReader.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the error received from the device:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION flg=0x10 (has extras) } in ph.com.healthpods.fragments.BaseFragment$3@3b8349d7
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:876)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5280)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot claim interface.
    at com.acs.smartcard.Reader.open(SourceFile:1613)
    at ph.com.healthpods.fragments.BaseFragment$3.onReceive(BaseFragment.java:278)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:866)
```

Comment: What kind USB device (class?), what error do you get? Please give us details, otherwise the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Hi @TurboJ, I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Show us code. Did you set the `force` paramater in `claimInterface()` to `true`?

Comment: @TurboJ thanks for your reply, I have updated the question and added a code snippet. I saw an issue here [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37032033](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37032033) is it the same issue? Is it possible to resolve this without upgrading the os version?